# I am trying to run MYSQL command using SSH on the remote server. Getting the below error

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am trying to run MYSQL command using SSH on the remote server. Getting the below error

```
ssh -p 22 root@eseemon63 "mysql --compress --secure-auth --database nacoma --execute 'SELECT time,object_name FROM changelog_history WHERE object_type = 'host' AND oldname = 'New Host' AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY time;'"
```

Error is:

```
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'Host AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY time;'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed by entering "'"

```
ssh -p 22 root@eseemon63 "mysql --compress --secure-auth --database nacoma --execute 'SELECT time,object_name FROM changelog_history WHERE object_type = 'host' AND oldname = 'New Host' AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY time;'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to escape the extra single quotes like below using `\` or using another `'`

```
ssh -p 22 root@eseemon63 "mysql --compress --secure-auth --database nacoma --execute 'SELECT time,object_name FROM changelog_history WHERE object_type = \'host\' AND oldname = \'New Host\' AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY time;'"
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, That is also not working .   Getting Below error                                                   
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(
bash: -c: line 0: `mysql --compress --secure-auth --database nacoma --execute 'SELECT time,object_name FROM changelog_history WHERE object_type = \'host\' AND oldname = \'New Host\' AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY time;''

Comment: @Madhanika, not working is very vogue ... specify the error you get